# How to group files by their paths in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Is some way to make from this list of strings:

```
['/User/someuser/file.py', '/tmp/download/file.zip', '/tmp/download/file2.zip', '/', '/usr/local/bin', '/tmp/file.txt']
```

make this list

```
[('/tmp/download', ('file.zip', 'file2.zip')), ('/tmp', ('file.txt',)),
 ('/User/someuser', ('file.py',)), ('/', ()), ('/usr/local/bin', ())]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have to realize it in pipeline, can't find a way.

Comment: can't mark because my reiting is 1

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) along with [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os

my_list = ['/User/someuser/file.py', '/tmp/download/file.zip', '/tmp/download/file2.zip', '/', '/usr/local/bin', '/tmp/file.txt']
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in my_list:
    if os.path.isdir(item):   # To check path is a directory
        _ = my_dict[item]   # will set default value as empty list
    else:
        path, file = os.path.split(item)
        my_dict[path].append(file)

# where `my_dict` is `dict` object holding value:
# {'/tmp/download': ['file.zip', 'file2.zip'], '/tmp': ['file.txt'], '/usr/local/bin': [], '/': [], '/User/someuser': ['file.py']}
```

In order to convert `my_dict` to list of desired format, do:

```
>>> my_dict.items()
[   # Formatted in order to make more readable
    ('/tmp/download', ['file.zip', 'file2.zip']), 
    ('/tmp', ['file.txt']), 
    ('/usr/local/bin', []), 
    ('/', []), 
    ('/User/someuser', ['file.py'])
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is an empty dir

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. You surely have a very *pythonic eyes* ;) Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) to split the path names into the dirname and the basename.  Then use `itertools.groupby` to group the files together.

```
import os
from itertools import groupby


l= ['/User/someuser/file.py', '/tmp/download/file.zip', '/tmp/download/file2.zip', '/', '/usr/local/bin', '/tmp/file.txt']

print([(k, tuple(i[1] for i in g)) for k, g in groupby(map(os.path.split, sorted(l)), key=lambda x: x[0])])
```

prints

```
[('/', ('',)), ('/User/someuser', ('file.py',)), ('/tmp/download', ('file.zip', 'file2.zip')), ('/tmp', ('file.txt',)), ('/usr/local', ('bin',))]
```

Comment: `groupby`, `map`, `sorted`, and *list comprehension* for achieving the single line solution is not the good idea over here. It seems to be toooo complex for simple task

Comment: That's exactly what i need

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is an empty dir

Comment: You can use `itemgetter(0)` instead of a lambda, I can be more readable…

Comment: If you can help please with it

Comment: How from this line:
[('/', ('',)), ('/User/someuser', ('file.py',)), ('/tmp/download', ('file.zip', 'file2.zip')), ('/tmp', ('file.txt',)), ('/usr/local', ('bin',))]

Make (using pipeline) this line:

[('py', 1), ('zip', 2), ('txt', 1)]

Comment: @ILyaShapira You can't really do that as a pipeline, because to produce one output you have to look at all of the inputs.  You can split the file extensions as a pipeline and hand that pipeline to a `Counter`.  `Counter(filter(lambda x: x, (os.path.splitext(base)[1] for dir, bases in l for base in bases)))` That's kind of complicated.  `Counter` is from `collections` module.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

```
from itertools import groupby
import os
L = ['/User/someuser/file.py', '/tmp/download/file.zip', '/tmp/download/file2.zip', '/', '/usr/local/bin', '/tmp/file.txt']
#if all files have extention, convert '/usr/local/bin' to '/usr/local/bin/'
L_fix =  [e if os.path.splitext(e)[1] else os.path.join(e,"") for e in L]
[(k,tuple(map(os.path.basename,v))) for k,v in groupby(L_fix, os.path.dirname)]
```

you get,

```
[('/User/someuser', ('file.py',)),
 ('/tmp/download', ('file.zip', 'file2.zip')),
 ('/', ('',)),
 ('/usr/local/bin', ('',)),
 ('/tmp', ('file.txt',))]
```

Comment: Thank you for help